# Is possible to know if the PC has the latest Windows updates from NET CORE 2.1

Tags: c#, windows, asp.net-core, updates, windows-update

I need to know if there is a piece of code in C# for .NET CORE 2.1 to know if the machine where the code is running, has the latest windows updates or eventually it needs to be updated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can separate the logic to PowerShell scripts, https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/2d191bcd-3308-4edd-9de2-88dff796b0bc and then call PowerShells scripts to carry the tasks. IT should work for .NET Framework and .NET Core.

Comment: You are aware that .net 2.1 programs ca nbe self contained and different programs can run different versions with NO version installed? If not - that is your problem. The installed version does not matter if a program comes with a newer version that it runs, which is never "installed" on the computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's anything native in .Net core, but you *could* shell out to wmic to get this information, the following command will list all installed updates: `wmic qfe list full`

Full wmic docs available at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmic

As a note of caution - obviously .NET Core is cross-platform whereas this is very much Windows specific...

Comment: Yes i know .NET CORE is cross-platform, for this particular application i need to test only in windows platform. Now I'm watching your documentation, and I'm trying to figure out if there is a solution for this problem.